# Conditional sumif for dynamically change range

Tags: excel

I want to use

```
=if((sumif(c1:c15,"ukw",b1:b15)>=12),(sumif(cX:c15,"ukw",bX:b15)),(sumif(c1:c15,"ukw",b1:b15))
```

Now I want `X` in `cX` should automatically change to `C` cell  number which when added satisfied the condition `>=12`.How to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make use of INDIRECT function along with the SUMIF.

Have a look at the following sites. They have some examples which explain the use. Give it a try - you should be able to resolve your problem with this.

https://www.thoughtco.com/excel-sum-indirect-dynamic-range-formula-3124100

https://superuser.com/questions/934329/how-to-use-indirect-with-a-sumif-formula-for-a-date-range

Hope this Helps.